# Firestore NSArray to Swift.Array match error

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I was following issue with using Firebase/Firestore SDK:

> Precondition failed: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type
>   Expected FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot but found FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot: file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-1001.2.63.12/swift/stdlib/public/core/ArrayBuffer.swift, line 346
>   2019-05-18 19:46:00.020040+0200 App[25051:288337] Precondition failed: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type
>   Expected FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot but found FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot: file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-1001.2.63.12/swift/stdlib/public/core/ArrayBuffer.swift, line 346

```swift
let listener = self.client
                .collection("countries/czechia/cities/\(id.rawValue)/venues")
                .addSnapshotListener({ (snapshot, error) in
                    guard let docs = snapshot?.documents else {
                        observer.onError(error!)
                        return
                    }

                    let arr: [Venue] = docs.compactMap { doc in // The code crashes on this line
                        do {
                            let decoded = try self.decoder.decode(Venue.self, from: doc.data())
                            return decoded
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                            return nil
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Never annotate types this way in a guard line: `guard let docs: [QueryDocumentSnapshot] = snapshot?.documents else {`. Conditional downcast the type:  `guard let docs = snapshot?.documents as? [QueryDocumentSnapshot] else {`

Comment: yep, sorry, it was for debugging purposes, i removed it, anyway the code still behaves the same

Comment: Try `let arr = docs.compactMap { doc -> Venue? in`

Comment: that does not help, the issue raises when I start iterating the `docs` array

Answer (score 0):

This error it's very common when you work with umbrella framework technique.
I was getting "***Precondition failed: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type
Expected FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot but found FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot bla bla bla bla...***" crash error in spite of having just one firebase instance reference to static framework working.

So I had to use the powerful NSObject features in particular Key-Value Coding protocol.

Check this....

```
let db = Firestore.firestore(app: firebase_instance)
    defaultsHelper.write(value: true, key: .isReceivingProspects)
    prospectosListener = db.collection("collection_name")
        .document("document_name")
        .collection("collection_name")
        .whereField("condition_parameter", arrayContains: "condition_value")
        .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
            weak var _self = self
            
            guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
                print("Error fetching document: \(error!)")
                return
            }
            
            // snapshot.documents or snapshot.documentChanges in a loop produces crash
            guard let documents = (snapshot as NSObject).value(forKey: "documentChanges") as? NSArray else { return }
            
            for document in documents {
                guard let object = document as? NSObject else { debugPrint("object was nil"); return }
                guard let type = object.value(forKey: "type") as? Int else { debugPrint("type was nil"); return }
                guard let docs = object.value(forKey: "document") as? NSObject else { debugPrint("document was nil"); return }
                guard let data = docs.value(forKey: "data") as? [String: Any] else { debugPrint("data was nil"); return }
                guard let fbModel = _self?.documentConverter.convertToNotificationModel(documentData: data) else {
                    debugPrint("fbModel was nil")
                    return
                }
            
                switch type {
                    case 0: // Added
                        _self?.onAddedOrModifiedNotificationEvent(fbModel: fbModel)
                    case 1: // Modified
                        _self?.onAddedOrModifiedNotificationEvent(fbModel: fbModel)
                    case 2: // Removed
                        _self?.onDeleteNotificationEvent(fbModel: fbModel)
                default:
                    debugPrint("Another option")
                }
            }
```